# OpenCL Vector components

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl

I have a question regarding my kernel code.
So I understand you cannot access a vector component in a kernel with `[]` square brackets like example `vec[2]`.

What are other ways to access it? Say I need to check if the vector element value is more than a certain value?

I am writing a kernel that parses `Array1` into a local memory vector `v`,
checks if any element in `v` is more than 5 and if so add into another vector call results.

Any advice on accessing the vector components in kernel?

```
__kernel void copy(__global int4* Array1, 
               __global int* Array2,
               __global int8* output
                ) 
{

    int id = get_global_id(0);

    __local int4 v;

    v = Array1[id];


    int8 v1 = vload8(0, Array2);
    int8 v2 = vload8(1, Array2);

    int8 results;


    /* My problem is here where i want to check if the current v[i] is more than 5, 
    if so add v1[i] into results, else add v2[i].*/


    if (any(v > 5)) {

             results.s0 = select(v2.s0, v1.s0, isgreater(v.s0, 5.0));
             results.s1 = select(v2.s1, v1.s1, isgreater(v.s1, 5.0));
             results.s2 = select(v2.s2, v1.s2, isgreater(v.s2, 5.0));
             results.s3 = select(v2.s3, v1.s3, isgreater(v.s3, 5.0));
             results.s4 = select(v2.s4, v1.s4, isgreater(v.s4, 5.0));
             results.s5 = select(v2.s5, v1.s5, isgreater(v.s5, 5.0));
             results.s6 = select(v2.s6, v1.s6, isgreater(v.s6, 5.0));
             results.s7 = select(v2.s7, v1.s7, isgreater(v.s7, 5.0));

             vstore8(results, 0, output);

    }
    else {
        /*does some other stuff that i haven't get to*/
    }


}
```

Comment: You can cast the base address of your vector component into the appropriate pointer type (int*), then you can use brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Detailed information about this can be found in the specification, see [6.1.7. Vector Components](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html#vector-components). In short, the components are named *x*, *y*, *z*, and *w* for *int4*, for your *int8* you need to use numeric indices: *v1.s0* to *v1.s7*. You can even access multiple components at the same time:

```
int8 large_vec = vload8(...);
int4 every_second_element = large_vec.s0246;
int last_element = large_vec.s7;
int2 first_elements = large_vec.xy; // Only works for the first four elements, xyzw
```

Components can also be accessed multiple times and in arbitrary order:

```
int4 vec = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int4 backwards = vec.wzyx; // {4, 3, 2, 1}
int4 multiple = vec.xxyy;  // {1, 1, 2, 2}
```

Comment: i am learning how to use the built-in select function, i want to use like so results = select(v2[i], v1[i], isgreater(v[i], 5)). How would i accesss the current vector index?

Comment: `select` already operates on vector types, so you do not need the indices here. `results = select(v1, v2, v > 5)` should give you the result.

Comment: Sorry Jan-Gerd i can't do that, since isgreater arguments has to be either datatypes like float and doubles, my `v` is a vector so there is no matching function call :(

Comment: My hardcoded method is to access individually :( i edited my code above to show

Comment: According to the specification, isgreater does work on vector types. Maybe I am reading your problem wrong. Could you give an example with inputs and expected output?